# multiline regex to capture just the last number of the outcome fails in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, global

I just want to get the very last number of all what ping returns:

```
    $s = ping 129.69.1.153 | out-string
    $s
    if ( $s -match '(?m).+(\d+)ms' ) {
        $Matches
    }
```

Google told (?m) is for multiline and .+ should be as greedy as possible.
But what I get is just the last number of the  2nd line not the last line????

```
     Ping wird ausgeführt für 129.69.1.153 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=31ms TTL=51
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=26ms TTL=51
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=27ms TTL=51
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=51

     Ping-Statistik für 129.69.1.153:
        Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
         (0% Verlust),
     Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
        Minimum = 25ms, Maximum = 31ms, Mittelwert = 27ms

     match: ..
     Name                           Value                                                                 
     ----                           -----                                                                 
     1                              31                                                                    
     0                              Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=31ms
```

Even a

```
     $s.Replace("`n","").Replace("`r","")
```

after the ping and before the match just matches the ms of the second line?

Any idea how this simple request can be solved in a simple way?

Thank you for your answers, but by fooling around I've fond it (s.b.):

```
    $s = ping 129.69.1.153 | out-string
    if ( $s -match '(?s).+\D(\d+)ms' ) { $Matches }
```

The (?s) does it:

```
     Ping wird ausgeführt für 129.69.1.153 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=51
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=27ms TTL=51
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=25ms TTL=51
     Antwort von 129.69.1.153: Bytes=32 Zeit=27ms TTL=51

     Ping-Statistik für 129.69.1.153:
         Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
         (0% Verlust),
     Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
         Minimum = 25ms, Maximum = 27ms, Mittelwert = 26ms

     match: ..

     Name                 Value                                                                         
     ----                 -----                                                                         
     1                    26                                                                            
     0                    ...
```

I don't know why - but it works.

Comment: What is the Powershell version you have? Test-Connection is built in cmdlet for doing something similar to ping (ICMP packets as well)

Comment: Can you show what it is you are trying to capture? The request is not clear...you want the very last response time? So from your sample data it would be 25ms?

Comment: @Noah Sparks: I wanted the 27ms it is the average: Mittelwert = 27ms. It is the very last number.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a hidden space at the end of the string which is why regex is having trouble. This works, just tested it.

```
($s.trim() | select-string "\d+(?=ms$)").Matches.Value
```

Alternatively you could do this, but I think trimming the spaces first would be preferable

```
($s | select-string "\d+(?=ms\s*$)").Matches.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to experiment with Test-Connection if you have a newer Powershell version

If not, I would suggest the following (since Regex is hardly ever a good idea)

```
$Tempfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$s = ping 129.69.1.153 | out-file $Tempfile
cat $Tempfile | Select-string "Antwort" | Select -last 1
Remove-item $Tempfile -force
```

Comment: I found the working match! Don't use (?m) multi-line but (?s) single-line: if ( $s -match '(?s).+\D(\d+)ms' ) { $Matches } - funny

Comment: How exactly is regex hardly ever a good idea? Instead you should have excessive useless code for something that could be much more simply accomplished?

Comment: Just a personal opinion as regex are well, fully non-intuitive (at least it does not appeal to my intuition). How is Regex simpler than the actual code I posted? `Select-String` does a search based on regex, but it returns lines (as `grep` does). This way OP can search for a keyword and select the proper statement (in case of ping, it will always be a constant value)

Answer (score 0):

If my assumtion is you are looking for `Mittelwert = 27ms` or the number `27` since you are refering to the last number in the ping.

If that is the case you can just look for that word as part of the match.

```
$s -match "Mittelwert\s+=\s+(\d+)ms"
```

**OR**

You can use named groups in your match

```
$s -match "Mittelwert\s+=\s+(?<Anzahl>\d+)ms"
```

So that you can run the following in place of `$matches`

```
$matches.Anzahl
```